# mongodb stream query with through2.spy end is not called

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node.js-stream

I have a streaming query from mongo and I am piping it to a through2 "spy" writeable stream. It works entirely including the "end" callback with a small collection of 5 documents. However, with a larger collection of 344 documents, only the first 15 come through, then it hangs forever, and the "end" event never fires. Here's a MCVE:

```
var spy = require("through2-spy").obj;
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

function getStream() {
  var stream = spy(function() {
    console.log("@bug counting", stream.total++);
  });
  stream.total = 0;
  return stream;
}

function onEnd() {
  console.log("ended");
}

MongoClient.connect(process.argv[2], function(error, db) {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return;
  }
  var stream = db.collection(process.argv[3]).find().stream();
  stream
    // behavior is the same with the follow line commented out or not
    .on("end", db.close.bind(db))
    .on("error", console.error)
    .on("end", onEnd)
    .pipe(getStream());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem's with `through2-spy` defaulting to using a `highWaterMark` of 16. To handle flow control, streams maintain an internal buffer that is cleared when data is consumed from them. Because there's no readable stream consuming data from the transform stream returned by `getStream`, the internal buffer gets filled and reaches the `highWaterMark`. Increasing the `highWaterMark` should fix it:

```
var stream = spy({highWaterMark: 350}, function() {
  console.log("@bug counting", stream.total++);
});
```

Another non-standard alternative is to reset the transform stream's readable state:

```
var stream = spy(function() {
    console.log("@bug counting", stream.total++);
    this._readableState.length = 0;
});
```

Comment: The highWaterMark option doesn't seem viable for real-world streaming applications. It just means the code breaks at some number higher than 16, but it still breaks. The _readableState approach seems to work no matter how many events traverse the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this is to ensure there's something downstream that will fully read the upstream source to completion. I ended up adding an extra `.pipe(terminus.devnull({objectMode: true});` to the end of my stream and that did the trick as well.

```
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
var spy = require("through2-spy").obj;
var terminus = require("terminus");

function getStream() {
  var stream = spy(function() {
    console.log("@bug counting", stream.total++);
  });
  stream.total = 0;
  return stream;
}

function onEnd() {
  console.log("ended");
}

MongoClient.connect(process.argv[2], function(error, db) {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return;
  }
  var stream = db.collection(process.argv[3]).find().stream();
  stream
    // behavior is the same with the follow line commented out or not
    .on("end", db.close.bind(db))
    .on("error", console.error)
    .on("end", onEnd)
    .pipe(getStream())
    .pipe(terminus.devnull({objectMode: true}));
});
```